# How to append a value in a new column to Null rows in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hello stackoverflow community

This is my sample data

```
Code      Sales   HeadQuarter
 CC       1000       XYZ
 AA       NaN        YYZ
 BB       2000       NaN
 DD       NaN        NaN
```

As I have to append a new column to respective rows that contains atleast one NaN value. The new column can contain any value. I'm using 1 as the value

The new table should look like this

```
Code       Sales        HeadQuarter   New_column
CC         1000           XYZ              
AA         NaN            YYZ            1
BB         2000           NaN            1
DD         NaN            NaN            1
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

Test missing values and get at least on `True` per row for mask and create new column in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.isna().any(axis=1), 'New_column'] = 1
print (df)
  Code   Sales HeadQuarter  New_column
0   CC  1000.0         XYZ         NaN
1   AA     NaN         YYZ         1.0
2   BB  2000.0         NaN         1.0
3   DD     NaN         NaN         1.0
```

If need set 2 values for match and not match use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['New_column']  = np.where(df.isna().any(axis=1), 1, '')
print (df)
  Code   Sales HeadQuarter New_column
0   CC  1000.0         XYZ           
1   AA     NaN         YYZ          1
2   BB  2000.0         NaN          1
3   DD     NaN         NaN          1
```